# Cant import submodules in python package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a python package that I can use standalone just fine. When I install it to site-packages with pip, though, I lose the ability to import submodules.

My package looks like this:

```
mypackage
    mypackage
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
        moduledir
            __init__.py
            mysubmodule.py
    setup.py
```

If I have the package on my pythonpath, I can use it just fine. But then when I use pip to install it to site-packages, I can't import submodules.

```
from mypackage import mymodule              # works fine
from mypackage.moduledir import mysubmodule # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named when installed to site-packages, works fine when on pythonpath
```

What's going on here? How do I change it so that I can import submodules?

Also, I'm sure this is answered somewhere, but I can't find it for the life of me on google or SO. I apologize if its trivial and I'm just googling the wrong terms.

Edit: Here is my setup.py as requested.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1',
      description='mypackage',
      url='https://gitlab.com/ericksonla/mypackage',
      author='ericksonla',
      author_email='ericksonla@ericksonla.com',
      license='',
      packages=['mypackage'],
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: `mypackage.moduledir` doesn't contain an `__init__.py`, so it's *not* a module.

Comment: Oops, just forgot to include it. It is in my actual package, just failed to type it in here. I updated the question.

Comment: We'll need to see contents of your `setup.py` file.  Is the distribution on PyPI?

Comment: I added the setup.py to the question. Its more or less just the example version. The distribution is proprietary so its not on PyPI.

Comment: When you install the package, is it installing the top level `mypackage` folder, or the inner one (that contains `moduledir`)? The nested folders with the same name might be confusing things if the wrong one is getting installed in the wrong place.

Comment: The process I'm using is navigating to the top level mypackage directory and then `pip install .`. I tried installing from the nested mypackage but it says 'setup.py not found'.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add the submodules to the packages list in `setup.py`:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1',
      description='mypackage',
      url='https://gitlab.com/ericksonla/mypackage',
      author='ericksonla',
      author_email='ericksonla@ericksonla.com',
      license='',
      packages=[
        'mypackage', 
        'mypackage.moduledir'],
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I'm still not quite sure why I need to import one level down, but not any further.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to see you found a `setuptools` solution that works for you. An alternative within `setuptools` that I recently learned about is the [`setuptools.find_packages()`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html) function. With the correct arguments, `setuptools.find_packages()` can discover and add an arbitrary number of submodules of your package, which folks may find useful for packages that grow in size and add submodules.

If you were to use this method in this example, your `setup.py` file might look like:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1',
      description='mypackage',
      url='https://gitlab.com/ericksonla/mypackage',
      author='ericksonla',
      author_email='ericksonla@ericksonla.com',
      license='',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False)
```

That flexibility comes with some caveats for more complicated use-cases, however.

For example, your current package structure gives your source code module the same name as the package itself (the code for `mypackage` is stored in directory `mypackage`). If you were to use a different directory structure, such as

```
mypackage
    src
        mypackage
            __init__.py
            mymodule.py
            moduledir
                __init__.py
                mysubmodule.py
    tests
        mytest.py
    setup.py
```

where the source code is in the `src` subdirectory, I think you would need to specify the "where" argument of `find_packages` in your `setup.py` file and add the `package_dir` argument to tell `setuptools.setup()` that it should map the contents of `src` to your package name, not to a `src` submodule:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1',
      description='mypackage',
      url='https://gitlab.com/ericksonla/mypackage',
      author='ericksonla',
      author_email='ericksonla@ericksonla.com',
      license='',
      packages=find_packages('src'),
      package_dir={'': 'src'}
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False)
```